# Populating data in Datalist issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, response

I am using following Javascript function to populate the `Datalist`:

```
function GetDropDownData(f) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Rentals/Base/GetContactsForFacility?selectedFacility=' + f,
        data: { facility: f },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            response($.map(result, function (item) {

                $('#custServiceContactsSelection').append($("<option     />").val(item.ContactName).text(item.ContactName));

            }));
        },

        cache: false,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (errorThrown.indexOf("Your session has timed out") != -1) {
                location.href = "/Rentals/Base/Timeout";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Following is the method inside my controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetContactsForFacility (string selectedFacility)
    {
        var facilityId = new Guid(selectedFacility);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var contacts = SessionService.AllCustomerServiceContactsForFacility(CrmService, facilityId);


            return Json(contacts.Select(x => new {  label = x.ContactName }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
        return Content(string.Empty);
    }
```

When I am trying to run this, it gets returned from Controller. But, after that, I get error in my VS: 
`JavaScript runtime error: 'response' is undefined`

I think, something is missing in the function `GetDropDownData()`, but not able to figure out what that exactly is.

Will you please guide me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AJAX request you need to change it to:

```
success: function ( response ) {
            $.map(response, function (item) {

                $('#custServiceContactsSelection').append($("<option     />").val(item.ContactName).text(item.ContactName));

            });
        },
        // rest of code
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! At least, the error has disappeared. But, I am still not able to see the Datalist. Let me get that working and I will let you know (and mark this as answer too!). :)

Comment: This is regarding same thing. I am not able to see the datalist in UI. It says that "Validation (XHTML 1.0 transitional): Element 'datalist' is not supported'. So, is there any other alternative that I can use which is similar to 'datalist' and captures the response sent?